# Portia interface fails to connect to server Safari

Tags: macos, docker, portia

I followed instruction from portia site: http://portia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
and installed it using docker and allocated port 9001 for portia to run. This is the response:

$docker run --rm -it -p 9001:9001 -v projects:/usr/src/app scrapinghub/portia

- action=
- shift
- '[' -z '' ']'
- _run
- service nginx start
  nginx: unrecognized service
- _set_env
- path=/app/portia_server:/app/slyd:/app/slybot
- export PYTHONPATH=/app/portia_server:/app/slyd:/app/slybot
- PYTHONPATH=/app/portia_server:/app/slyd:/app/slybot
- echo /app/portia_server:/app/slyd:/app/slybot
  /app/portia_server:/app/slyd:/app/slybot
- /app/portia_server/manage.py runserver
- /app/slyd/bin/slyd -p 9002 -r /app/portiaui/dist
  2017-10-26 04:55:36+0000 [-] Log opened.
  2017-10-26 04:55:36.222260 [-] Splash version: 2.3.3
  2017-10-26 04:55:36.222687 [-] WARNING: Lua scripting is not available because 'lupa' Python package is not installed
  2017-10-26 04:55:36.222862 [-] Qt 5.5.1, PyQt 5.5.1, WebKit 538.1, sip 4.17, Twisted 17.9.0
  2017-10-26 04:55:36.223037 [-] Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) [GCC 4.8.4]
  2017-10-26 04:55:36.223285 [-] Open files limit: 1048576
  2017-10-26 04:55:36.223434 [-] Can't bump open files limit
  2017-10-26 04:55:36.452879 [-] Xvfb is started: ['Xvfb', ':1451098581', '-screen', '0', '1024x768x24', '-nolisten', 'tcp']
  2017-10-26 04:55:37.991820 [-] Site starting on 9002
  2017-10-26 04:55:37.992049 [-] Starting factory 
  Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 26, 2017 - 04:55:38
Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'portia_server.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

But when I try to open http://localhost:9001
I get that server unexpectedly dropped connection.

Can anyone explain what is going on and provide a solution?
Thank you